# Backbone and PHP API

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, backbone.js

I have couple of questions about implementing a PHP api behind a backbone client.

The PHP api that I am writing is meant to be RESTful and as result works OK with `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` request.

However the usage of the API has grown massively and as result we are wanting to streamline requests.

We can a collection of projects, by doing the following on the client side,

`var projects = new App.Collections.Projects();

 projects.fetch({ reset: true });`

It is worth noting at this point that a project can have one of 4 status, archived, pending, active, completed.

This fires a GET request `http://app.com/projects` this returns all the projects for a user the test user we are using it returns 1200 projects (each project is a rather large amount of data). This is resulting in PHP running out of memory.

What we want to is streamline the request, so instead of requesting the data in one block it requests the data in 4 go.

> i.e Get all pending projects - then get all completed projects etc

We would first have to create a collection for each project status, then run a fetch for each status, and then merge results into one collection, does this seem like a sensible option?

Does it go against REST thinking or the use backbone models and collections?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The one that's coming right now in my mind is to modify the server to handle a query parameter say `status` and then pass `status` while fetching the collection.

```
var projects = new App.Collections.Projects();
projects.fetch({
  reset: true,
  data:{ status : 'ACTIVE'} 
  }).done(function(){
    projects.fetch({
      data : { status: 'ARCHIVED'},
      remove:false
      }).done(function(){
          projects.fetch({
            remove:false,
            data : {status:'PENDING'}
          });
      })
});
```

Passing query parameters to a REST backend is perfectly fine, it's nothing against.

References :

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15996003/566092